# In MVC, how to return a single value from list using foreach

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using `foreach` condition to take a particular value from the table. But the primary value is same and child values are different. So the result is returning multiple parent values.

**My code is**

```
<%foreach (DJ.Models.Color cpf in Model.Colors)
              { %>
                <%:cpf.Behaviour.Name %><%:","%>
            <%} %>
```

My Result is come as follows,

```
Red,
Red,
Red
```

Because the child values are contains

```
Red- one
Red- two
Red- three.
```

At the same time the possibility will come different results also. I want to show the result like if the same **color** have different objects it should return single value. otherwise multiple,.. how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%foreach (var cn in Model.Colors.Select(c => c.Behaviour.Name).Distinct())
          { %>
            <%:cn %><%:","%>
        <%} %>
```

Comment: Error is showing in foreach `cannot convert type string to Model.Colors`

Comment: Corrected the error. I gave `Model.Color in Model.Colors` , so the error is returned.